# Log plugin installs and delete plugins completely in Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

Simply put, is there a plugin (or a way) to log plugin installs along with their incoming database table entries? I'm currently trying to clean up my install and remove plugins I no longer need. Uninstalling the plugin is a start, but when looking at the database, many of these plugins still leave table entries in an event to maintain settings just in case the user reinstalls the plugin at a later date.

Do I need to try to traceback all of these table entries to their plugin developer, or is there a better way? Going ahead, is there a plugin that I can use to monitor this so I can keep the database from getting too dirty?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good idea to have some way to log all the options a plugin dumps in wp_options.

I use [Clean Options « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/clean-options/) to be able to clean out old plugin cruft from the WordPress options table. The plugin hasn't been updated in awhile, but it still works on 3.9.

As for standalone tables, any table that is not a default WP has been added by a plugin. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

In my experience, some plugins add large numbers of tables that can get quite large, and sometimes the plugin aren't designed very well, and those tables remain even with a correct uninstall from WordPress admin.